# How to add YouTube video id to metadata when downloading video with youtube-dl

Tags: python, video, youtube, youtube-dl

I use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) to download playlist on YouTube.

My command is like this:

```
youtube-dl --add-metadata --download-archive "J:/Video/Download/YouTube/archive/PLOJ1nP1cWwjExMSJqTw9nDrtoB7x_U4El.txt" -c -i -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4][height <=? 1080]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo[height <=? 1080] +bestaudio/best[height <=? 1080] " --merge-output-format mp4 -o "J:/Video/Download/YouTube/playlist/%(playlist)s/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOJ1nP1cWwjExMSJqTw9nDrtoB7x_U4El
```

it would add youtube video author、title and description to video file's metadata which is exactly what I want.

but except that， I also what the youtube video id save to metadata, it this possible?

Do I have to use Python to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the optional parameter:
--metadata-from-title FORMAT

The FORMAT follows the same formatting as the output template. Therefore you would add:

```
--metadata-from-title "%(id)s"
```